# Qml / Qt creator: How to "spawn"/create a custom component multiple times

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

Trying to make a UI for a program in Qt creator.

I got a scroll view where I want to place a custom component (a rectangle). I can manually put the component in there multiple times and scroll up and down so got that working.

My problem is that I want to generate the component automatically when the user presses a button.

**So my question is how to "generate/spawn/create" a custom component into a scroll view when the user presses a button**

So far I've tried with loaders and calling the custom component directly inside an onClicked function but this does not seem to work.

> var component = Qt.createComponent("CustomComponent.qml");
>
> ```
>             onClicked: {
>                 component.createObject(column);
> ```

I am trying to create the component inside a column with the id column

you can compare what I am trying to achieve with a social media feed. Where I got a list that is scrollable and I want to put components(atm just a rectangle) in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Repeater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) for that:

```
Repeater {
    id: repeater
    model: 0

    CustomComponent {}
}

Button {
    onClicked: {
        repeater.model += 1;
    }
}
```

Repeaters can be used in positioning items(Row, Column, Grid) and layouts.
Also it is possible use a list as a model. So in that case you can reach model data(model[index]) with `modelData` and index with `index` in your custom component.

Comment: First of all thanks alot for the answer.

Ive kinda got it working to the point where it will generate a new component. The proplem is that it seams to delete the prior one whenever i load the repeator again.

How could I solve this?

Comment: I don't think there is way to actually store qml components. One way achieve it saving model data somewhere. Simplest but kinda ugly solution is making it invisible instead of reloading.

Comment: If you can't figure it out feel free to append a concrete example to your question, so I will append a solution my answer.

Comment: Alright. Also thought about the invisible thing and im properly just going to go with that for now(proplem with that is just that its "finite" and not never ending but its not a huge proplem). Thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: @Christian Maybe what you need is [ListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html). It creates items dynamically when they visible to user. It is also using quite similar model system.

Comment: Maybe your right will definitely try it out.